# update join table taking a very long time

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have a table `citations` with 5 million rows with following info:

```
Paperkey1 | Year1 | Paperkey2 | Year2 
100                   20
200                   90
300                   80
```

And another table `pub_year` with around 3 million rows with following info:

```
Paperkey | Year
100        2001
200        2002
20         2003
90         2004
80         2005
```

I want to update the table `citations` by taking the year value from table `pub_year`. I used the following query but its been running for more than 3 hours and still its not finished yet.

```
update citations T2

join pub_year T1 on T2.paperkey1= T1.paperkey

set T2.year1 = T1.year;
```

Is there anybody who knows what are the main reason that its taking too long? Im not sure if it ever finish if i keep letting it runs. Or is there something wrong with my query? 
The paperkey fields are all in varchar and the year fields are all in integer. Thank you.

Here is the update after running EXPLAIN:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an index on the columns you're joining on?

Comment: @barmar the only thing i have is the paperkey, which is the key i got from the raw dataset. I've never tried to apply indexing on this. Do you mean I have to convert the paperkey using indexing?

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM citations T2 JOIN pub_year T1 ON T2.paperkey1 = T1.paperkey` and update the question with the result.

Comment: @axiac I updated the question with the explain query result screenshot

Comment: Is there a paperkey3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second row has value `ALL` in column `type`. This is the cause of the very, very slow execution. For each of the 5 million rows from `citations` it needs to scan all the 3 million rows of table `pub_year` in order to find the matching rows for the `JOIN` clause. An index will fix that.

Add an index on column `Paperkey1` of table `citations`:

```
ALTER TABLE `citations` ADD INDEX (`Paperkey1`);
```

Also add an index on column `Paperkey` of table `pub_year`:

```
ALTER TABLE `pub_year` ADD INDEX (`Paperkey`);
```

If one of the two tables already contain an index on the aforementioned column (or it is the first column in a multi-column index) then skip that table; having identical indexes doesn't help.

After the indexes are created (they will take some time to complete, especially if there is other activity on these tables in the same time), run the `EXPLAIN` again and check the result.
You should get `ref` or `eq_ref` in the column `type` of the second row.

Now the `UPDATE` will complete faster. It will still take a couple of minutes (or even more if the tables are accessed by other processes during the query) but this OK when you update 5 million records.

For performance reasons, on `INNER JOIN`s it's recommended to put first the table that produces the smallest number of rows in the final result set. In this case, that table is `pub_year`:

```
UPDATE pub_year T1
INNER JOIN citations T2 ON T2.paperkey1 = T1.paperkey
SET T2.year1 = T1.year
```

*(As a side note, the MySQL query optimizer is smart enough to change the query and put the tables in the order that provides the best execution time. You can see that in the result of the `EXPLAIN` query from the question: table `T1` (`pub_year`) comes first.)*

Comment: that worked very fast! thanks so much. However, I found some year who is still with null value while actually they exist in the other table. i wonder what the cause of this kind of problem.

Comment: Before running the `UPDATE` you can turn it into a `SELECT` to find out how many rows will it modify. Keep the tables and the `JOIN`s, keep the `WHERE` conditions, drop the `SET` clause, add `COUNT()` of relevant field(s) in `SELECT`.